# silverlight map application like showcase on silverlight.net

Tags: silverlight, dictionary

we want to make application like [silverlight showcase Mapview](http://www.silverlight.net/showcase/) 
where we can search by different category on left hand side panel or people can select country or region on map. can anyone suggest some sample or guidelines to implement this?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the complexity and obvious expense, I would be really impressed if anything like that was released as a sample (Microsoft are you listening?). It requires a lot of data to drive it.

I have been involved in [creating a Xaml World map from scratch (below)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846709/looking-for-a-simple-silverlight-map-component) and that alone took nearly a day for a stylised polygon version (no fine detail)....

[image]

Quoting myself: "You import a map as a background image and use the pen tool to dot-to-dot trace around the country. Combine all those path segments into a single path. Then create a separate poly-path for each state (close them to allow for a fill)."

Once you create them you can name the individual country polygons and connect up mouse  logic to make them all glow on mouse over or change colour on press etc.

Basically all the other stuff on that screen are user controls and custom controls. Work out the behaviour you want and create controls to suit your own needs.

Comment: Thanks. i found useful info from the link you suggested