# Creating an interactive map in XAML/C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I'm looking into creating an application that takes an interior .pdf map of a building, and displays information about each room as it is clicked. Relatively simple, but I'm a bit stuck on the best way to achieve this as a native Win10 app.

The most recent Stack Overflow answer I found was this one:

[Looking for a simple Silverlight map component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846709/looking-for-a-simple-silverlight-map-component)

But it's old. Anyone have more up to date tips on how to essentially trace over the existing schematic so that I can start coding each room in the map?

Thanks,

N

Comment: Have you checked this[doucment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images)?

Comment: I'd love to know if someone has an elegant way solution to loading in a pdf and converting to path data reliably on demand. However if it's just you taking a pdf and doing the conversion manually that's [not too tough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350165/is-there-any-way-to-make-geometrydrawing-interactive-from-the-ui-or-how-to-loa).

Comment: Thanks so much! Just what I was looking for.